# location.split("#"); does not work in jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to split the url of a page using `#`.

I was using `location.split("#");` but it does not seem to work in jQuery.

I want to get the last portion of the URL, after `#`, for example:

> http://example.com/#/hello_world -> /hello_world
>
> http://example.com/folder/dir/#test -> test

How can I achieve this?

Comment: could you show the code you tried..!

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: If you plan on doing anything more complicated than that, I recommended the jsbbq library, http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Answer (score 6):

You actually want `location.hash`, which will return exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: In some browsers `location.hash` returns a string with a leading "#" and some without. For safety, always use `location.hash.replace('#','')`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

```
location.href.split('#')
```

[location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location) is an object not a string, if you want the complete location path then you can use the hreg property of location

Another solution is to use `location.hash` which will give the string after the `#`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
location.hash.substr(1);
```

Here's why:

```
typeof location; //"object", .split won't work on objects
typeof location.hash; //"string", now it will works!
```

Also just remember this has nothing to do with jQuery, or else... https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif